# Accessing Gatsby env variables in gatsby-config

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, gatsby

I am new to Gatsby and am trying to access my environment variables inside of my `gatsby-config.js` file in local development. I want to be able to test this all locally.

`.env.development`

```
GATSBY_KEY=stuffvaluehere
```

`gatsby-config.js`

```
{
  key: process.env.GATSBY_KEY,
}
```

Whenever I run `gatsby develop` I get an error that the value is undefined. I can't tell exactly from the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/) what I would need to do in order to access these variables locally before storing them in Netlify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you miss adding the path of your `.env` in your `gatsby-config.js` file

Add this line of code at the very top of your `gatsby-config.js`

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

if still no luck, try to install dotenv

```
yarn add dotenv // yarn
npm install dotenv // npm
```